# gocode external package give no suggestion for vscode

Tags: go, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

My auto-complete / intellisense stopped working after upgrading from the Go extension here of Visual Studio Code: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go

I've opened an issue in there, but I'm thinking this might have to do with gocode.

I'm running Windows 10, Go version 1.5.1, Visual Studio Code 0.10.5 and Go extension 0.6.21. Was working fine before updating and I was using Go extension 0.6.17.

Problem is suggestions / intellisense works for internal package, but every external package I have no longer give suggestions when writing . or ctrl+space. Even net/http or core Go package does not work.

I wanted to try and run gocode myself to see what it's actually returning, so I've looked into the code for the extension and it is executing a child process similar to that: `gocode -f=json autocomplete filename offset`.

Not really sure how to get `offset` or what it represents, number of bytes for position that triggers the auto-complete? In any case, when I run this I got no output and I do not return to the prompt, I have to CTRL+C to return.

I'm unable to find anything interesting on Google either, probably wrongly searching or not exactly knowing what to search for.

Does someone would have an idea, goal of running gocode was to see if in fact the gocode was returning suggestion for external package than if yes, there's something with the extension.

If gocode does not returns anything, well it means it's not working properly now, anything I can do?

Thanks

Edit 1: Log from `gocode` following [kostya answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34428285/316855)

`2015/12/23 07:26:11 Import path "github.com/gocraft/web" was not resolved
2015/12/23 07:26:11 Gocode's build context is:
2015/12/23 07:26:11  GOROOT: c:\go
2015/12/23 07:26:11  GOPATH:
2015/12/23 07:26:11  GOOS: windows
2015/12/23 07:26:11  GOARCH: amd64
2015/12/23 07:26:11  GBProjectRoot: ""
2015/12/23 07:26:11  lib-path: ""`

It seems my GOPATH variable is not evaluated, but it's set, and when I run `echo %GOPATH%` I receive the correct value.

Comment: Where is the `gocode` log located that you refer to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try running gocode server process in the console and observe the output:

```
gocode close
gocode -debug -s
```

Make sure that you are running the latest version of gocode:

```
go get -u github.com/mdempsky/gocode
```

You might want to run the following command to build gocode instead (though I believe you won't be able to use debug method that I suggested in this case):

```
go get -u -ldflags -H=windowsgui github.com/mdempsky/gocode
```

as suggested at https://github.com/mdempsky/gocode

Comment: Thanks @kostya, seems my GOPATH is not set, but it is when I run echo %GOPATH%, any idea why that would be?

Comment: I just saw your issue in gocode project. Possibly a bug in the VS plugin. I don't use it, so cannot help you unfortunately.

Comment: I found the issue on the extension and posted it to the vscode extension GitHub issue. If anyone have this error here's how I fixed it locally for now: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/167

Comment: Boom, thanks, ran first 3 lines above and started working again.

Comment: The `github.com/nsf/gocode` repo is no longer maintained. Recommended version is now `github.com/mdempsky/gocode`.